# Interchanging the process of substitution and solving

Tags: systems-of-equations, substitution

I've always wondered about this type of thing, but never figured out why.

Say we have an equation $h+rx-x^3 = 0$ where $h,r$ are real-valued parameters.

If we substitute $h=0$ and then solve for $x$, the solution set is different versus if we solve the equation for $x$ and then substitute $h=0$.

Why is this? Is there any general reasoning behind this for systems of equations of arbitrary size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution set should be the same. Why do you say they are different? Perhaps it's easier with a quadratic, say $h+rx-x^2=0$ where you can actually solve for $x$.

Then by the first method we substitute $h=0$ to get $rx-x^2=0$, so $x=r$ or $x=0$.

By the second method we use the quadratic equation to get $x=\frac{r\pm \sqrt{r^2+4h}}{2}$, and substituting $h=0$ we get $x=\frac{r\pm r}{2}$, i.e., $x=r$ or $x=0$.

Comment: I see. When I solved the cubic in Mathematica, the solutions turned out to be equivalent - just written in very different forms. You're right - it's easier to see with a quadratic.